# How to write \n without making a newline

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write this exact string but I don't \n to make a new line I want to actually print \n on the screen. Any thoughts on how to go about this? (using python

Languages:\npython\nc\njava

Comment: Either escape the backslash or use a raw string.

Comment: Use a raw string like `r'foo\nbar'`, or use the ``\\`` escape sequence like `'foo\\nbar'`.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do but in a string in python you would just use this for example: ```test = '\\n'``` So basically use an extra backslash to escape any escape characters, which is what a backslash for example is

Comment: Aye thanks a lot guys !! I got it to work!!

Answer (score 0):

adding a backslash will interpret the succeeding backslash character literally. `print("\\n")`.

Answer (score 0):

Either *escape* the backslash by preceding it with another backslash:

```
'Languages:\\npython\\nc\\njava'
```

Or use a *raw string* by preceding the literal with an `r`:

```
r'Languages:\npython\nc\njava'
```